# write regular expression code in java

Tags: java, regex

please help me guys i want to know how to write a regular expression code.

lets say that a file contain 3 sentences

```
[hi Tom how are you.hey Andy its nice to see you.where is your wife Tom.]
```

so when i search for `Tom` i want the program to print the first and last sentences and if i search for `Andy` the program should print the second sentence only .

i got crazy because all what i did is just print `Tom` or `Andy`.
this is my code:

```
 Pattern p =Pattern.compile("Tom\\w+")
```

Comment: What is definition of a sentence?

Comment: your pattern matches the word "Tom" followed by one or more word-characters. Your example sentences has none of those, it only has "Tom" followed by not-word-characters. You might not like this, because it involves reading, but go read http://www.regular-expressions.info, to learn how to use regular expressions. It's maybe a few hours of your life that will pay off forever after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question right, you want to match 2 sentences for `Tom` and 1 for `Andy`. You want do this:

```
String line = "hi Tom how are you.hey Andy its nice to see you.where is your wife Tom.";

String pattern = "[\\w\\s]*Tom[\\w\\s]*[\\.]?";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Find: " + m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
Find: hi Tom how are you.
Find: where is your wife Tom.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a complete beginner, then try the code below. You can make it more efficient by checking for multiple keys/people names in one iteration itself.

```
public class Tommy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String junk = "hi Tom how are you.hey Andy its nice to see you.where is your wife Tom.";
        System.out.println(junk);
        String [] rez = extractor(junk, "Tom");
        printArray(rez);

    }

    public static String[] extractor(String text, String key) {
        String[] parts = text.split("\\.");
        String[] rez = new String[parts.length];// Use an arraylist ?

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (parts[i].contains(key)) {
                rez[i] = parts[i];
            }
        }

        return rez;
    }

    public static void printArray(String[] ar) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] != null) {
                System.out.println(ar[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose that each sentence ends with `"."` then:

```
public List<String> findMatches(String string, String name) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w\\s]*" + name + "[\\w\\s]*");    
    for (String s : string.split("\\.")) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if(p.matcher(s).matches())
            result.add(s);
    }
    return result;
}


String string = "hi Tom how are you. hey Andy its nice to see you. where is your wife Tom.";
System.out.println(findMatches(string, "Tom");
System.out.println(findMatches(string, "Andy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[^.]*?\bTom\b[^.]*\.)([\w\s]+(?=\.))
```

Try this for `Tom`.For `Andy` replace Tom with Andy.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/10